# What array function should I use for creating an index?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

Hello guys I am trying to create an index of all words on html page that my crawler parses.
At this moment I have managed to breakdown the html page into an array of words and I have filtered out all the stop words.

At this stage I have a few problems.

The array of words from the parsed html page have words that are repeated, I like that because I still have to record how many times a word appeared in the page.

The array looks like this.

```
$wordsFromHTML =    
array (size=119)
      0 => string 'web' (length=3)
      1 => string 'giants' (length=6)
      2 => string 'vryheid' (length=7)
      3 => string 'news' (length=4)
      4 => string 'access' (length=6)
      5 => string 'mails' (length=5)
      6 => string 'mobile' (length=6)
      7 => string 'february' (length=8)
      8 => string 'access' (length=6)
      9 => string 'mails' (length=5)
     10 => string 'web' (length=3)
     11 => string 'february' (length=8)
     12 => string 'access' (length=6)
     13 => string 'mails' (length=5)
     14 => string 'desktop' (length=7)
     15 => string 'february' (length=8)
     16 => string 'hosting' (length=7)
     17 => string 'web' (length=3)
     18 => string 'giants' (length=6)
     19 => string 'vryheid' (length=7)
     20 => string 'february' (length=8)
     22 => string 'us' (length=2)
```

Now I want to save all the words from the $wordsFromHTML to the $indesArray which is my final index.

It should look like this.

```
$indexArray = array('web'=>array('url'=>array(0,10,17)))
```

The problem is how to keep incrementing the position (`$wordsFromHTML` keys) for each word that was repeated from the `$wordsFromHTML` array in the final index array.

The index array should only have unique words and if another word that already exists try to come in, we use the already existing word which has the same URL and increment its position.

Hope you understand my question.

Comment: You've not specified what language you're using.

Comment: by the way i am using php

Comment: Have you looked at http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php

Comment: I think that counts characters and i am not interested in characters, my concern is how to push the position of a string that happened more than once to the available array of position. and thats if they are all from the same url

Comment: Using array_keys function has helped me to get all the keys of repeated word just as i wanted. thanks for your contr all

Comment: Please answer your own question by placing an answer to it and accept it later. This is how the site works in case you've found an answer your own.